# Add JQuery spinner after scrolling to end of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code to append more contents into Div but unsure where to add the image loader so it shows at bottom of page before new contents are added.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {   
    $.getJSON("http://howtodeployit.com/?json=recentstories", function(data) {
    newposts = data.posts.slice(currentPostcount, currentPostcount + desiredPosts);
    $.each(newposts, function(key, val) {
        //Append new contents
        $("#postlist").listview().listview('refresh');
        });
    });
}});
```

I have tried this but it requires AJAX:

```
beforeSend: function() { $('#loader').show(); },
complete: function() { $('#loader').hide(); },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {   
        $('#loader').show(); 
        $.getJSON("http://howtodeployit.com/?json=recentstories", function(data) {
            $('#loader').hide(); 
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                //Append new contents
                $("#postlist").listview().listview('refresh');
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried though it shows on reaching end of page but it never disappears

Comment: you are getting the response as data, where as in `$.each` you're using `newposts` may be this is making issue over here, please check it. i've edited my answer, pls check it.

Comment: And also pls check what this line `$("#postlist").listview().listview('refresh');` refers to, it also causes you errors.

Comment: I have updated the code to show you how the data feed is gotten and loaded into **newposts**. What is now happening is when I scroll and it appends the next contents, the spinner stays on but only disappears when the last content is loaded

Comment: Are you hiding loader after the ajax request ? use `$('#loader').hide(); ` in success callback of `getJSON` request.